# Reading from a textfile and taking those values into a 7 by 7 matrix

Tags: c

Hey guys so I am kind of stuck on what to do. I know what I want in pseudo code but having some difficulty actually writing it.

I have 2 arrays of 7 numbers. In the first array the numbers are

```
 Angstroms      [0.4000, 0.5000, 0.6000, 0.7000, 0.8000, 0.9000, 1.0000]
 Energy         [-0.9767, -1.1000, -1.1535, -1.1710, -1.1704, -1.1604, -1.145]

  Input File
  0.400000000000000  -0.976798125297645
  0.500000000000000  -1.10086977056789
  0.600000000000000  -1.153517976992553
  0.700000000000000  -1.171014611491842
  0.800000000000000  -1.170406254407191
  0.900000000000000  -1.160412786280990
  1.000000000000000  -1.145758813825982
```

Now I want to fit them to a sixth order polynomial so I can do more stuff with that data which is the problem I am having. 
My output for this stage would be this

```
 A = Angstroms
 [1     1      1      1      1      1      1
-0.4  -0.5   -0.6   -0.7   -0.8   -0.9   -1.0
 A^2   A^2    A^2    A^2    A^2    A^2    A^2  So the above value squared
 A^3   A^3    A^3    A^3    A^3    A^3    A^3   and so on
 A^4   A^4    A^4    A^4    A^4    A^4    A^4
 A^5   A^5    A^5    A^5    A^5    A^5    A^5
 A^6   A^6    A^6    A^6    A^6    A^6    A^6]
```

How do I pull the list and then add it to this matrix and then in a short efficient manner with each next row being like a^2, a^3 and so on.

I have an idea of just inputting every value like

A(0,0) = 1 ; A(0,1) = -0.4 and so on but that would be super tedious.

My code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ELEMENTS 6
#define n 7

// First read the data from the file 
// Fit the data to a sixth order polynomial 
// Fit the data to sixth order polynomial in terms of exp(-r) 
// Plot the fitted functions and the data points to a set between 0.2 and 5 A

void * file_input ();
void * polynomial ();
int main () {

 file_input();
 return 0;

}

void * file_input () {

   static double Angstroms[ELEMENTS];
   static double Energy[ELEMENTS];

   float a, b;
   int i;

   FILE * in_file = fopen("H2Data.txt", "r");
   for (i = 0; i <= ELEMENTS; i++) {
        fscanf(in_file,"%f %f\n", &a, &b);
        Angstroms[i] = a;
        Energy[i] = b;
//          printf ("Angstroms[%f], Energy[%f]\n", Angstroms[i], Energy[i]);
   }
   return in_file, Angstroms, Energy;
   fclose(in_file);

}

// Sextic equation ax^6 + bx^5 + cx^4 + dx^3 + ex^2 +fx + g = 0

void * polynomial(Angstroms, Energy) {

  int i, j;
  double * ax = malloc (n * n * sizeof(double)); // 7 by 7 matrix
  double * b = malloc (n * sizeof(double));      // 0 by 1 matrix for the      b values
}
```

Comment: Please show (the first few lines of) your input file. verbatim.

Comment: 0.400000000000000  -0.976798125297645
0.500000000000000  -1.100869770567898
0.600000000000000  -1.153517976992553
0.700000000000000  -1.171014611491842
0.800000000000000  -1.170406254407191
0.900000000000000  -1.160412786280990
1.000000000000000  -1.145758813825982

Comment: Please add this to your question. Make sure the newline show correctly.

Comment: Ya sorry just did it right now it didn't come out right in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ELEMENTS 7
#define N 7

double Angstroms[ELEMENTS];
double Energy[ELEMENTS];
double ax[ELEMENTS][N];

void file_input();
void polynomial();

int main () {
 file_input();
 polynomial();
 return 0;
}

void file_input () {
   float a, b;
   int i;
   FILE * in_file = fopen("H2Data.txt", "r");
   for (i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
        fscanf(in_file,"%f %f\n", &a, &b);
        Angstroms[i] = a;
        Energy[i] = b;
   }
   fclose(in_file);   
}

void polynomial() {
  int i,j;
  for( i=0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
  {
    ax[i][0] = 1;
    ax[i][1] = Angstroms[i];
  }
  for( i=2; i < N; i++)
    for (j=0; j < ELEMENTS; j++)
    {
      ax[j][i] = ax[j][i-1]*ax[i][1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double * ax = malloc (n * n * sizeof(double)); // 7 by 7 matrix
double * bx = malloc (n * sizeof(double));     // 0 by 1 matrix for the b values
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    fscanf(in_file,"%f %f\n", &a, &b);        
    bx[i] = b; // Energy
    ax[0,i] = 1;
    ax[1,i] = a; // Angstroms
    ax[2,i] = a*a; // a^2
    ...
}
```

It allocates enough space for the vector and the matrix, then for each file in the input file fills one element of the vector and one column in your matrix.